# Toolbar/Actionbar not showing in API16

Tags: android

In my app, I currently have 2 activities. I'm able to get the toolbar to display in the second one, but on the main one it won't show up in earlier APIs. If I run it on a Marshmallow device, it works fine, but I've tried running it on an emulator with API16 (4.1) and the toolbar just isn't there. I can open my second activity, and the toolbar for that appears, but not in the main one even though I have them implemented exactly the same. In my activity xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#fafafa"
    tools:context=".Quotr">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_quoter" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/mainFab"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        />


    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change colors"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mainFab"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then in my onCreate I have

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

This is my styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="NoActionBarTransparentNav" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

If I'm forgetting to post anything, the full source is at:
https://github.com/Ashanmaril/Quotr

For some reason the toolbar will display on Marshmallow and whatnot, but not in Jellybean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I had to wrap my toolbar in a LinearLayout for it to work

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
```

And that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In .java use

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

or

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity??
```

And try to force

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13) {
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setLogo(R.drawable.myicon);
    bar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Extending Activity breaks setActionBar() and ActionBarActivity is deprecated in place of AppCompatActivity which is what I'm using. I gave it a shot anyway and it didn't change anything.